# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() with SESSION variable

Tags: php, session, foreach

I'm doing a cart for a web configurator and I've a problem.
I got this:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION["pedido"]) && is_array($_SESSION["pedido"])) {
        echo "Ha seleccionado:";
        foreach($_SESSION['pedido'] as $prod => $unidades) {
            echo "$unidades unidades de $prod";
```

When I execute it on `MAMP`, it works well, but on my server, it shows the error:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()` in [lineOfCode].
I've tried to search a solution, for example, casting the `$_SESSION['pedido']` to array, and it works, until I got the `$prod` key, that is not the correct (its returns a `0` instead of the product key), and I need that `key` for a switch operation.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you `var_dump($_SESSION['pedido'])` on your server before the `foreach` to confirm you're getting what you expect? Can you show us the result?

Comment: Have you tried outputting the content of your array using print_r($_SESSION["pedido"]) for debug purposes. You might have overlooked something causing $_SESSION["pedido"] to not contain what you expect it to.

Comment: Maybe the session is not started? `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Can't see how this could ever throw that error at that particular point. The foreach would only execute if it the `if()` test succeeded, and part of that test is REQUIRING that the session var be an array.

Comment: I've tried to use this:
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_SESSION['pedido']);
    echo '</pre>';
And also I've tried the var_dump.
But it doesn't show anything. What Im doing wrong?

Comment: The strange thing is that in the MAMP server, the code work perfectly, the $_SESSION got the correct values... 
And its strange that I can get to that point but it just work (incorrectly) if I do the cast.

Comment: well, yeah. `(array)null` will turn null in an empty array, as would `(array)$undefinedvar`.

Comment: But in the MAMP server, it return the correct value, and even if on this server the array is empty, if I made the cast, it returns 0... not null.
Also if the variable is undefined, it doesn't must show an error when I exec the 'if'?

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?
To your knowledge, the php version is 5.3.3 on the web server, and the version in the MAMP server is 5.6.10